# WooCommerce make checkout field mandatory if

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created several new checkout fields for my checkout page.
One field is the first radio button with *"type klant"* this lets the user choose between customer type (business or private). When either is selected, some fields are hidden/shown by me with Javascript.

The *"bedrijfsnaam"* (business name) field is shown when *"bedrijf"* (business) is selected, it is not required. If made required and the user selects *"particulier"* (private) the field is not hidden with js, but present html-wise, so when completing, the validation gives an error to enter the business name.

How can I change the validation to only check the business name field when business is selected in customer type?

I probably have to do something with the `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process' );` to make the required check based on the radio button, but I got stuck there, any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Suggesting you a better plugin for this:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-checkout-field-editor-pro/

You can add multiple checkout fields and make them required. Also you can change lables of existing fields.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Maha! I looked at this plugin and did not find the option to make a field's required boolean dependent on another field value, am I right?

Comment: Thanks Maha, but this is not what I'm trying to achieve, I need to make it conditional.... All the stuff the plugin you mentioned does, I already did myself by adding code to my functions.php. please read my initial question again

Comment: This just doesn't answer to the OP question. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57148040/2394994