# Show hide Order notes field based on a checkbox in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

In Woocommerce checkout page there is a "ship-to-different-address" checkbox and I would like when it is checked, to hide `order_comments` field *(Order notes)*. If the checkbox is unchecked back again, `order_comments` field should be visible *(unhidden)*.

Is this possible in functions.php?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will hide Order notes section field when "ship-to-different-address" checkbox is checked and vice versa:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'checkout_custom_script_js');
function checkout_custom_script_js() {
    // Only on front-end and checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $('form.checkout').on( 'change', '#ship-to-different-address-checkbox', function(){
            if( $(this).prop('checked') === true )
                $('#order_comments_field').hide(); // Show
            else
                $('#order_comments_field').show(); // Hide
        })
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Comment: Hi

This is great and works, but only if "order_comments" is not a required field.
My field is a required one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Koangi For showing hiding fields in checkout, see [this related recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55209546/3730754), that will show you how it works in something a bit different…